# Cant find theWebBrowser Item in my Toolbox

Tags: visual-studio, winforms

I want to play around with login in to Twitter/Facebook via c#, in all Videos i watched so far they used a WebBrowser ,as a Display to see the Webpage you are currently but i dont have this Items in my toolbox. Most of them use VS 2010 , and I use VS2017.

I tried to find packages to get the WebBrowser to appear in my Toolbox but i didnt find anything

Comment: The `WebBrowser` class is part of the System.Windows.Forms namespace. If you have created a WinForms application, this control is there. You need to have a Form opened in the designer to see controls in the ToolBox.

Comment: It's usually the last control in the "All Windows Forms" control panel in the Toolbox.

Comment: ... or the last in Common Controls. The ToolBox has also a Search Field. This, of course, if you have selected a Windows Forms project as template.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is a WebForms type, youll not find this option.

Be sure your project is a Windows Forms type.

To check your project type in VS, double click properties and check the "Output type" field.

Comment: I use a Windows Forms APP (.NET Framework) and the Output type is  a Windows Application , still dont see the WebBrowser Item